# Cheap interface and speaker

Tags: m-audio, imac, 5.1, 7.1, external

I have iMac and I am looking to buy some cheap 5.1 or 7.1 external audio card and set of speakers for my home. I don't need anything hi-level because most of my work I do in studio.
[image]
<sub>(source: [m-audio.com](http://www.m-audio.com/images/global/media_hqpics/ProFire610-front.jpg))</sub>

So far I only find M-Audio [ProFire 610](https://web.archive.org/web/20141007092745/http://www.m-audio.com:80/products/en_us/ProFire610.html?), that suit my needs. Does anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the [MOTU](http://www.motu.com/products/motuaudio) stuff...(I've had 828's since v1) as well as the [Presonus](http://www.presonus.com/products/Detail.aspx?ProductId=5) stuff.

Comment: I'm another 828 user and while some models in some years the quality control has been spotty, when you get a good one, they're great. I had an 828mkII for six years with no tears.

Comment: My MKII went a little wonky, but both the MKI and MKIII have been flawless. My mentor/boss has used an Ultralite for a few years without issues until he had it modded. But I have read about some folks having QC issues. I may have just been lucky. Then again, a friend of mine went through three Firestations before he got a working one...

Comment: MKIII was a consideration for me but I really need more than 2 XLRs in. I think I'm going for the Focusrite Saffire Pro 40 as it has the 8 XLRs and can have 7.1 out, have a look at that one too. It doesn't do 192kHz which is a downside (if you wanted that) but I have no equipment capable of recording that high anyway.

Answer (score 1):

i have a presonus audiobox usb and it's great! great neutrok preamp, no latency, good building quality and very low price

Answer (score 1):

I love RME gear.  I've had 3 over the years.  Not a second of trouble.  Set and forget (which is what I want from an interface).